# How can I install the current stable version of Git on CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, git

I'm interested in installing Git on a CentOS Linux 5.4 host.

The [installation instructions](http://progit.org/book/ch1-4.html) in the Pro Git book online offer two avenues: installing from source or using the host's package management system (in this case, yum).

However, neither is working for me.

**Install from yum**

When I try yum I get this result...

```
$ sudo yum install git-core
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.team-cymru.org
 * extras: centos.mirrors.tds.net
 * updates: ftp.osuosl.org
Setting up Install Process
No package git-core available.
Nothing to do
```

(Why would yum not find such a commonplace package? Does it have to do with Kernel.org being down?)

**Install from source**

The other option is to download the source.

The location of the latest stable version of Git, v1.7.6.1, given on the [main Git website](http://git-scm.com/download) is http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.7.6.1.tar.bz2.

However that link leads to a page saying "down for maintenance". It appears that kernel.org has been down for a couple weeks due to an attack.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is because CentOS only contains packages found in RHEL, and older versions of RHEL do not have Git. If you want Git via Yum then you will need to enable [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). Note that it does not necessarily contain the latest version though.

The second is... unfortunate, and there's not anything you can do about it. Stick to EPEL for now.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. But hunting around among related questions, I found this guy mentioning [rpmforge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge). Maybe I should go with that, as it comes directly from CentOS?

Comment: RPMForge is independent of CentOS.

Comment: Out of eagerness I enabled RPMForge. It seemed to work. It installed the current version of Git. Thanks for the help!